# why or operator is not working in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have a html form in php page and the form is processed in same php after submit:

```
page:1: form.php
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="25" />
 <input type="hidden" name="typid" value="250" />
 Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="Mr.X" /><br />
 Address: <input type="text" name="address" value="USA" /><br />
 Mobile: <input type="text" name="mobile" value="1234567890" /><br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']){
  foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if($key!='id' || $key!='typid'){
      echo $key.' : '.$value.'<br />';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

according to the condition inside foreach loop, the output should be like this:

```
 name : Mr.X
 address : USA
 mobile: 1234567890
```

but it is giving output like this:

```
 id : 25
 tpid : 250
 name : Mr.X
 address : USA
 mobile: 1234567890
```

If I remove one condition from 'if' condition inside foreach loop like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']){
  foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if($key!='id'){
      echo $key.' : '.$value.'<br />';
    }
  }
}
```

the output is as expected:

```
 tpid : 250
 name : Mr.X
 address : USA
 mobile: 1234567890
```

why the OR (||) operator is not working in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OR condition is not fit for this.

`OR` condition returns true if any of the conditions is true.

You want that both the conditions are `true`.

You have check that the `$key` is not `id` and also not `typid`.

You need AND condition.

Corrected code:

```
if($key!='id' && $key!='typid'){
```

Comment: This is the right answer and worked as I expected. But could not understand why OR does not work. The logic should be "If the $key not equal to 'id' OR if the $key not equal to 'typid' then echo $key and $value". But if I use and it becomes: "If the $key not equal to 'id' AND if the $key not equal to 'typid' then echo $key and $value". What is the reason behind this?

Comment: The reason is that, in your loop, you are getting any key. That key is either not id or not typid. If I take name, name is not id or name is not typid, which is returning true. So, it is not working. For AND, the key is not id and key is not typid, which is true, so, works.

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid, if my answer worked for you, please accept it as solution and other users can gain.

Comment: I already accepted it and up vote it before you requested. Thank you.

Comment: You need to click on right symbol against my votes on this answer. So that it becomes green. :)

Comment: Thanks @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid.

Answer (score 2):

if($key!='id' || $key!='typid')

OR Condition :-

1 0 = 1

0 1 = 1

0 0 = 0

1 1 = 1

or will always print until both statement false.

AND Condition :-

1 0 = 0

0 1 = 0

0 0 = 0

1 1 = 1

so AND Condition will be the perfect for your expectations.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### Errors

1. In `if(isset($_POST['submit']){` missing closing `)`
2. use `'` in String compare

So final Well-Form Answer is

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="25" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tpid" value="250" />
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="Mr.X" /><br />
    Address: <input type="text" name="address" value="USA" /><br />
    Mobile: <input type="text" name="mobile" value="1234567890" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))//changed
    {
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
        {
            if($key!='id' && $key!='typid')//changed
            {
                echo $key.' : '.$value.'<br />';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: for typid what is the output

Comment: @raghavendra I'm not bother about his logic. i Just show what's wrong. ok !

Comment: he corrected question already. it should be in and 'condition ' that is it answer for the question